# CMS for Complex Membership website

Tags: drupal, content-management-system, expressionengine

Which one better drupal or expressionEngine? Must handle page/event specific membership management. Anyone have experience on those two CMS?

Comment: You really should take a few moments and expand on your question.  For one thing, I've no idea what you mean by "page/event specfici membership management".

Comment: The idea is to have similar BuddyPress (Wordpress) which display member profile in frontend plus the event specific (e.g. event schedule with registration option). Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't matter what platform you use to do this, it depends on how its implemented. You could even do it with Wordpress.

That said, Drupal has a lot of out of the box functionality to accomplish this. Not sure about EE.

Comment: I'm using wordpress currently, what add on can handle complex membership for WP? Base on your experience.. Thanks Kevin.